# Downloads are shown as harful in Edge browser

Tags: download, warnings, microsoft-edge, smartscreen

We have a web application. There we allow users to download one .msi (microsoft installer file) file related to our application. Recently we have made some changes to this .msi file and published new version in the web application. All of a sudden when we download this file, Microsoft edge browser is prompting warning message and saying that ".msi was blocked because it could harm your device." Can anyone help us to resolve this issue? Below are the screenshots for your understanding. Based on my analysis Microsoft SmartScreen software raise this warning. But not sure how to rectify this issue completely for our users.

Below message when we click on download button in the portal.

[image: warning message in edge browser]

The below warning when we install the downloaded .msi file

[image]

Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks
Nag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we see the second picture, you can notice that `Publisher: Unknown publisher`.

[image]

It should contain the publisher information and your MSI file needs to properly signed. This can be the possible reason that MS SmartScreen is finding this MSI file harmful because no publisher information is available.

You can try to add that information and properly signed the MSI file can help to fix this issue.

If you are not sure how to add that information then for that issue, I suggest you create a new thread in a relevant forum.

Comment: Thanks for the info.